# how to specify the main class when packaging with maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am wondering if there is any way to specify which main class I want my maven to use as reference, something like

```
mvn package -DmainClass=com.myMainClass
```

Dont want to modify the pom or the plugin itself, just send it as parameter, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`maven-jar-plugin` jar goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) defines a `archive` parameter with the 
[`org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration`](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) type that defines the 
`mainClass` parameter.
But the `archive` parameter doesn't have a `User property` associated to that allows to provide the value as argument in the command line execution.
Note that the `maven-assembly-plugin` that allows also  to package the artifact as a JAR will not be more helpful : the `archive` parameter is not defined as a `User property` either.

So you don't have the choice (at least with the `maven-jar-plugin`): you have to use the `mainClass` property in the pom.xml.

Now if it makes sense, you can make this value dynamic : value `mainClass` in the pom.xml with a custom user property that you pass from the command line.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
           <archive>
              <manifest>                
                <mainClass>${my.mainClass}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
           </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

And execute :

```
mvn package -Dmy.mainClass=com.myMainClass
```